# Jquery effect on "appearing" text?

Tags: jquery

Assuming this simple HTML

```
<input autofocus="autofocus"  type="password" id="inputId" name="inputName"/>
<p id="textId"></p>
```

I want to to do this with jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#inputId').keyup(function () {
            $('#textId').text('customText')       
        })
    })
```

But I want to add an effect to the `.text()` function, something like the "transition" effect of the css.

How I can do this?

Comment: animate opacity and change text on animation end, then animate again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) `p` first than [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputId').keyup(function () {
        $('#textId').hide().text('customText').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#inputId').keyup(function () {
            $('#textId').hide().text('customText').delay(1000).fadeIn();      
        })
    })
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5ZJL/7/)